# Decomposition of homomorphism of semisimple.

Tags: semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a semisimple lie algebra,
Then $L$ can be decomposed as $L=m_{1}L_{1} \oplus m_{2}L_{2}\oplus...\oplus m_{r}L_r$

I want to show that :

If $\varphi : L \longrightarrow L $ is an homomorphism
Then

$\varphi=\varphi_{1} \oplus \varphi_{2} \oplus... \oplus \varphi_{r} $

Any help.

Where $\varphi_{i} =\varphi |_{m_{i}L} $

Answer (score 2):

Write $m L_i=L_i^{j_1}\oplus ..\oplus L_i^{j_m}$.

The restriction $\varphi_{j_l}:L_i^{j_j}\rightarrow L$ is a morphism of Lie algebras. Since $L_i^{j_l}$ is simple, $Ker(\varphi_{j_l})=0$ or $L_i^{j_l}$. If $Ker(\varphi_{j_l})=0$, then the image of $\varphi_{j_l}$ is a sub Lie algebra of $L$ isomorphic to $L_i^{j_l}$ this implies that $Im(\varphi_{j_l})$ is $L_i^{j_p}$, we deduce that the image of $\varphi_i$ is contained in $mL_i$ and $\varphi=\varphi_1\oplus...\oplus\varphi_m$.

Comment: Thanks, If you know a course about this , please send me